# .NET application with WEB GUI

Tags: .net, user-interface

I'm just thinking how is it possible to create, for example, server part of application on C# but without GUI (console, for example), but create GUI in WEB.. like on home routers WEB UI, to connect by IP:Port to my server part?..

Is there any specific technologies or smth?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

WCF, Web Services, remoting.. etc. All those are valid answers... Depends on your scenario...

Answer (score 1):

If you create an ASP.NET application it will be run on the server and can be displayed from any browser.

Comment: Yes, but problem is that for example ASP.NET again is for web, but it can't be a server side part of application :) So, I need C# application with WEB UI, that is the question :)

Answer (score 1):

This is possible through WCF and Windows Services. You can create you Server Application that will run as a service on the hose machine and then create a web application that connects to the server via WCF. Depending on what you are wanting to achieve this shouldn't be too difficult

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, as I know, WCF is just a communication technology. So, as a resolving could be creating a standalone server app as a Windows Service that will work with client apps through web services (through WCF) and create another WEB application (better on Java + JavaScript?) which will connect to my server service again through WCF... Right?

Answer (score 0):

Let's remember: the web has no GUI. Your web browser displays a string of text (HTML) that the server pumps out. It's all HTTP back-and-forth.  Your home router is the same thing: a service listening on a port that returns HTML back to you. You choose to display this return with a web browser. The web has no GUI, it's your browser's interpretation and display that acts as a GUI.

You can achieve the same by creating an ASP.NET application. This could be a web service, a web application that uses web forms/pages and the HTTP protocol. That'd be the easiest way to develop a .NET application available on the web. It's a matter of deciding which 'services' to offer your users via HTTP: web pages, or web services with JSON or XML as the data being passed between.

Comment: Yes, I know how WEB works :)
I need dynamic content (some messages, visual statistic, etc.), so the easiest way, I think, is to create Silverlight application so, but I don't think that it's the right way and the better is to work with HTML5 somehow...